# Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly: Python 3+

Tags: python, int, typeerror

My code is supposed to determine and display the number of binary trees after an input.
I keep getting the `can't convert int object to str implicitly` error and I have no idea how to fix it.  It easily works in versions of Python under 3.0, so please help, as I'm still a beginner in Python and I would like to understand what I'm doing wrong.

```
import sys
print ("Welcome to Binary Tree Enumeration!")
x = input("Type an integer to output its binary trees: ")
print ("\nYou entered " + str(x))
def distinct(x):
     leafnode = '.'
     dp = []
     newset = set()
     newset.add(leafnode)
     dp.append(newset)
     for i in range(1,x):
         newset = set()
         for j in range(i):
             for leftchild in dp[j]:
                 for rightchild in dp[i-j-1]:
                     newset.add(("(") + leftchild + rightchild + (")"))
         dp.append(newset)
     return dp[-1]
 alltrees = distinct(x+1)
 for tree in alltrees:
     print (tree)
 print ("Thank you for trying this out!")
```

I forgot to add...this is the error I'm getting.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 29, in 
    alltrees = distinct(x+1)
TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly
```

Comment: The error you get should at least indicate which line the error occurred on, it might be helpful to include this as the answers so far have concentrated on the `newset.add` line, but I suspect that the error occurs at `distinct(x+1)`

Comment: Yes sorry, I forgot to add that.  This is the error I'm getting...

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 29, in 
    alltrees = distinct(x+1)
TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly

Comment: You should edit the question to include that information. People will hopefully edit their answers to be more specific to the actual error (although it's along the same lines as what they've already said)

Comment: Added it in there, thanks for that tip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have suggested, this comes from your call to `input`. In Python27:

```
>>> input() + 1
3 # I entered that
4
```

But using `raw_input()` (which has the same behaviour as `input` in Python3+):

```
>>> raw_input() + 1
3 # I entered that
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects
```

And indeed, we have:

```
>>> x = raw_input()
3
>>> type(x)
<type 'str'>
```

In your code, your user-input `x` is a string, and the code complains on the line `distinct(x+1)` when you try to add a string and an int. Convert it first like this:

```
>>> x = int(input())
...
```

Comment: Wow, that definitely helped me understand it better, and I was able to solve it now.  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

In order to concatenate strings and string representations of various types, you have to cast the latter to strings explicitly, e. g.

```
"(" + str(leftchild) + ", " + str(rightchild) + ")"
```

or, more readably,

```
"(%i, %i)" % (leftchild, rightchild)
```

Comment: Concatenating strings with `+` is evil

Comment: Thanks for that advice, but it's still not solving the error I'm having.  I forgot to add it before, so it's included in my question now.

Answer (score 0):

By default when you use `input` its always a string input

```
x = input("Type an integer to output its binary trees: ")
print ("\nYou entered " + str(x))
```

So there's no need to convert it again !

and here use `.format()`

```
newset.add("{0} {1} {2} {3}".format(r"(", leftchild, rightchild, r")"))
```

But the above one will not maintain the datastructure !!

If you would like to preserve the datastructure, use,

```
newset.add(tuple(leftchild, rightchild))
```

Comment: Isn't adding hard coded parens using formatting a bit ugly? Why aren't they part of the format string?

Comment: @SpoonMeiser, you are correct, If you feel that's little ugly, you can try using `tuple()` instead

Comment: I was thinking more `"( {0} {1} )".format(leftchild, rightchild)`, just including the parens in the format string. But yes, depending on how the data's being used, a tuple might be a good idea.